# how to install Google Cloud Tools for visual studio ion Visual Studio 2019 Community?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio 2019 through Online Extension, it does not show up in the search results

I tried installing the extension manually, still can't install it, I have multiple version of Visual Studio installed one of which is VS 2015, which is not supported. So I am getting this error

```
28-05-2019 09:51:15 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

According to the documentation prerequisite is VS2017, is it only available for VS 2017?

Answer (score 1):

As of this posting, there is still not a 2019 compatible extension.  Since my primary use-case was using it for deployments, I used the following script (batch file) to do it. Hopefully someone finds use in this!

Run the following at the root of your project folder.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet publish -c Release
copy app.yaml .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
gcloud app deploy .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\app.yaml -q
gcloud app browse
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on searching the Visual Studio marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/GoogleCloudTools) it appears this extension is only available for 2017.

Maybe there is an update in development, but you'll need a way to contact to authors to confirm this.

While some extensions can be loaded into 2019 by unzipping the VSIX file, modifying the manifest and re-zipping, there is no guarantee this will work at all (let alone not lead to crashes or other more subtle errors).

The 2017 version pages does link to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio and that shows an open source licence, so maybe you could make changes yourself and push a PR?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart now says it supports 2019 (for Windows)